# Replace Jar in DLL

Tags: java, c#, dll, jar

I have a dll that is used in one of our web application, the dll has a Jar embedded as a resource. The jar is signed by someones certificate that isn't a trusted cert, I pulled the jar out, removed the signature, resigned with a trusted certificate and now I need to put the jar back in the dll.

Is there anyway to do this? I've tried using ResourceEditor but it doesn't show any information. I do not have the source code that was put into the library as the person who originally sent the dll to us has since retired.

Any assistance would be appreciated, please let me know if there is any information I need to add.

EDIT: Please tell me what I did wrong if you are going to down vote my question so I can try to correct my mistake.

Comment: I'd try going back to the source C# project.  Put the new jar in as a replacement of the old one, and rebuild the DLL.

Comment: @IanMcLaird I work for a state government and we were given this application from another state, we have been trying to get in touch with their developers but they're ignoring our calls. I was trying to reverse engineer it myself since we can't get the source C files at least right now. Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the tool Telerik JustDecompile, which decompiled the dll into a visual studio project.

I took the jar out and resigned it, then recompiled the dll in visual studio.

All is good now!